# CSS border appears on click

Tags: html, css, border

[image: LOGOUT]

I have this simple logout button on the right (blue coloured) button and whenever I press the logout button, that border appears

I have tried the following CSS styles:

```
a:active
{
    border-style: none;
    border: 0px;
}
```

and these have been tried on all `<a> tag` possibilities like `hover, active`..

Any idea what might be the cause?

this is the **Jsfiddle** link

http://jsfiddle.net/v1x29f9h/

Comment: For accessibility reasons I wouldn't remove this. People without mice will not know which links/buttons they are on unless there is some sort of outline.

Comment: This is mostly for my thesis website, it's not going to actually out to public. And if you press 'TAB' , around the words log out a border will still appear

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not a border, it's the outline.

```
#logoutButton {
    outline: none;
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/v1x29f9h/1/

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Guess border-style wasn't the right choice here

Comment: @DodoSerebro You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Your answer was a big help

Answer (score 3):

It is `outline: none;`. The border would follow the border-radius path.